# Installation is incomplete at 98%

Tags: magento

I am trying to install brand new magento. But got error in console log

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Theme':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Customer':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Installing schema...
```

I am installing Magento on localhost and install 2 time but everytime showing me same error. Installation stop at 98% since last 30 minutes.

Not sure why this is happening.

Any help should be apprecaited.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for any Error Logs.  Go to this [link](https://alankent.me/2015/07/16/the-dreaded-70-and-98-magento-2-install-pauses-quick-note/) . If issue not resolved.